# jBPM5 Task Instances Sequence for Display

Tags: workflow, jbpm

Please assume the following scenario,
In a process flow there are three humanTask1, humanTask2, humanTask3; All three are assigned to same userA;

Now, assume there are two process instances (p1, p2) live. Each process instance can be in different tasklevel.

That is, for p1, task status are as, humanTask3-inprogress and for p2, humanTask1-inprogress

To display the tasks for this userA in a web page, I want them to be ordered as they appear in workflow design like,

1. p2-humanTask1
2. p1-humanTask3

`taskService.getTasksOwned()` may not return the tasks list in this order.

How do I ensure the tasks are displayed in this sequence?

I am using jBPM 5.3; `LocalTaskService`;

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You will have to decide your own order and then apply it whether by ordering the result of taskService.getTasksOwned() or by creating  and executing a customized version of the query that taskService.getTasksOwned() is using.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks. For a Human Task, there is a field named MetaData for which I am able to add key-value like (sequence,1). How can I access this MetaData field through API? I checked Task.java If I can access it, I can assign sequence at design time and order based on that at runtime.